# How large must the characteristic of $k$ be, for the cohomology of the Lie algebra $\mathfrak{sl}_n(k)$ to be exterior as in characteristic zero?

Tags: homological-algebra, lie-algebras, characteristic-p, lie-algebra-cohomology, modular-lie-algebras

$\DeclareMathOperator\SU{SU}$In this question, all Lie algebra cohomology is of the form $H^*(\mathfrak{g}; k)$, with $k$ the trivial one-dimensional representation of $\mathfrak{g}$. All Lie algebra cohomology in this question is ordinary (not restricted).

Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field of characteristic $p>0$. Here is my question: I would like to know a reference which establishes the primes $p$ for which the cohomology ring $H^*(\mathfrak{sl}_n(k); k)$ is an exterior algebra on generators $x_3, x_5, ..., x_{2n-1}$, with $x_i$ in degree $i$. If the result is well-known but folklore, I would appreciate being told of that as well.

---

Everything below this point is further explanation of the question, and can be skipped. If $k$ were instead $\mathbb{C}$, then it is quite classical that $H^*(\mathfrak{sl}_n(k);k)$ is an exterior algebra on generators in the degrees described above. However, the argument familiar to me involves showing that $\mathfrak{sl}_n(\mathbb{C})$ is isomorphic to $\mathfrak{su}(n)\otimes_{\mathbb{R}}\mathbb{C}$, then using Lie theory to establish that the cohomology of $\mathfrak{su}(n)$ agrees with the cohomology of the Lie group $\SU(n)$, whose cohomology can be built up inductively using fiber sequences and the Serre spectral sequences. This argument does not generalize very well to positive characteristic, since ordinary Lie algebra cohomology does not agree with the cohomology of the positive-characteristic analogues of compact simply-connected Lie groups.

Nevertheless, I know how to show that, for $k$ of characteristic $p$ and $p\gg n$, $H^*(\mathfrak{sl}_n(k); k)$ is indeed exterior on classes in the degrees described above. But I do not know exactly how large $p$ must be, to get this isomorphism. I would like to know this. Surely this is known among people who work on Lie algebras in positive characteristic, but I have found only one reference: [On Cohomology of Simple Modules for Modular Classical Lie Algebras](https://www.mdpi.com/2075-1680/11/2/78), a 2022 paper of Ibraev, Kainbaeva, and Melikozhaeva, claims that $H^*(\mathfrak{sl}_n(k); k)$ is indeed exterior of the form I described, as long as $p$ exceeds the Coxeter number of $\mathfrak{sl}_n(k)$, which is $n$. This looks right to me, and agrees with calculations I have made for low values of $n$. However, the proof offered by Ibraev-Kainbaeva-Melikozhaeva is cryptic to me. It is terse in a way that suggests to me that this argument is folklore among people who work on Lie algebras in positive characteristic, so I hope others can tell me if this kind of argument and result is indeed well-known.

The argument given by Ibraev-Kainbaeva-Melikozhaeva appears to be simply by pointing out that, if $p$ exceeds the Coxeter number of $\mathfrak{sl}_n(k)$, then the Killing form on $\mathfrak{sl}_n(k)$ is nondegenerate. (This is a strong condition: unlike in characteristic zero, not all semisimple Lie algebras over fields of positive characteristic have nondegenerate Killing form.) Ibraev-Kainbaeva-Melikozhaeva write that this implies that "the cohomology results for one-dimensional trivial module in characteristic zero remain valid also for positive characteristics of an algebraically closed ﬁeld." I think the authors must have in mind a purely algebraic way to make the characteristic zero calculations, unlike the argument I described above which passes through Lie groups.

For the characteristic zero calculations, Ibraev-Kainbaeva-Melikozhaeva cite the book chapter "Cohomologies of Lie Groups and Lie Algebras" by Feigin and Fuchs, and while I think I understand the explanation given in Feigin-Fuchs, I cannot say I understand it well enough to be sure it also works in positive characteristic. One good answer to my question would be simply to inform me that this argument is indeed known to work perfectly well in positive characteristic (but a reference for this would be greatly appreciated). Feigin and Fuchs write that the integers $1, ..., n-1$ are the "exponents" of $\SU(n)$, i.e., that those integers are "one less than the degrees of homogeneous polynomials in the Cartan subalgebra, invariant with respect to the Weyl group and constituting a minimal system of generators in the ring of such polynomials." Feigin and Fuchs then state that, for a finite-dimensional simple Lie $\mathbb{C}$-algebra $L$, its cohomology $H^*(L;\mathbb{C})$ is an exterior algebra on generators whose degrees are one greater than twice the exponents. Of course this indeed gives the correct answer for $\SU(n)$. Feigin and Fuchs do not include a proof of this theorem. If there is a place where I may find a proof of theorem in which it is relatively easy to see that it still holds in positive characteristic as long as the Killing form is nondegenerate, that would be an excellent answer to my question.

Thanks!

Comment: You should look at the purely algebraic proof of the semisimplicity of the f.d.representation theory of a semisimple algebra, which depends only the non degeneracy of the Killing form and uses the Casimir element acting on cohomology. The same circle of ideas should do the trick.

Comment: If you're interested by a "bad but explicit" bound with little effort, it could go as follows: the homology comes from the non-vanishing of various minors, depending on structure coefficients (arranged to be integral). So if $p$ is greater than all these minors, then modulo $p$, the Betti numbers are the same.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez Thank you for the suggestion. I think I know the algebraic proof you mean, except that it only yields that certain short exact sequences split, yielding only vanishing of $H^1(sl_n(k);k)$. I do not know how to deduce from this that the higher cohomology groups form an exterior algebra. Do you have in mind a particular reference which might discuss this? Thanks again.

Comment: @YCor Thank you for the suggestion. The argument you describe is not far off from the proof I know, that if $p>>n$ then the cohomology of $sl_n(k)$ is as it is in characteristic zero. But I did not attempt to write an explicit bound on $p$ by this strategy, because the only way I know to do it, the bound will be enormous, far worse than the expected bound $p>n$ from the Coxeter number of $sl_n$.

Comment: @user509184 that $p\gg 1$ implies that it's as in char zero (for fixed $n$) is a trivial fact. The point is to quantify it.